# Remove Search.strtpoint.com Search Engine

Tags: safari, google-chrome, search-engine

I, perhaps unwisely, installed `iFunBox` based on an article in a respected Computer Magazine `APC`.

This appears to have installed a Search Engine in my browsers.
It was easy to remove from `Firefox`, but I can't seem to delete `search.strtpoint.com` from Chrome.

Safari now crashes whenever I run it.

Any ideas on how to fix these problems?

---

EDIT
I have managed to fix Chrome.

Comment: It looks like if we leave you alone for a while, you will find a solution for Safari as well :)

Comment: ok, use terminal "mdfind Search.strtpoint.com" to find it

Comment: @Buscar웃 thanks for the suggestion, it was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have solved my problem.

I got an exception from `Safari` which suggested "External Modification Warnings: Thread creation by external task."

I found many references on the web (most for Windows) and some suggesting going to `Safari\Preferences\Extensions` and turning off. I wasn't even going to try those which suggested I install yet another app from the web.

Seeing as I could not even start `Safari` the above was not useful. I could start `Safari` in Safe mode, but there was nothing there - possibly because when it originally wanted access to all my private data I refused.

`Activity Monitor` showed an `Installer` and this had `~/Library/Application Support/com.genieoinnovation.Installer/Completer.app/Contents/MacOS/Installer` open.
I deleted this directory. Unfortunately this did not fix the problem.

I tried @Buscar웃 suggestion, but this only found references to old preferences in Firefox and Chrome, which I had already fixed.

I then tried `sudo mdfind com.genieoinnovation` and found the following.

```
/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.genieoinnovation.macextension.client.plist
/Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/com.genieoinnovation.macextension.client
/Library/Frameworks/GenieoExtra.framework/Contents/Library/LaunchServices/com.genieoinnovation.macextension.client
/Library/Frameworks/GenieoExtra.framework/Contents/Resources/en.lproj/com.genieoinnovation.macextension.plist
/Library/LaunchAgents/com.genieoinnovation.macextension.plist

/Users/ian/Library/Application Support/com.genieoinnovation.Installer/Completer.app/Contents/MacOS/Installer
```

Deleting all these seems to have resolved the issue.

Comment: I knew you can do it :) with a happy ending! me like happy endings.

Answer (score 0):

Paste "chrome://extensions/" to the Chrome address bar and hit Enter on the keyboard.
Scroll down the page, look at Search > Manage search engines. Then you will find search.strtpoint.com.

[image]

Then click Show advanced settings link and click Reset browser settings button. The two tips may help you. If search.strtpoint.com comes back again, this means that the browser hijacker makes modifications to registry keys. Perhaps you can check out this search.strtpoint.com manual removal guide to [get more details](http://blog.doofix.com/how-to-get-rid-of-search-strtpoint-com-redirect-virus/).

[image]